# C#: Generic interfaces and understanding "type parameter declaration must be an identifier not a type"

Tags: generics, interface

I'm trying to understand the generic interface as described in [this](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2008/03/using-irepository-pattern-with-linq-to.html)

My example has an interface:

```
  public interface ITest<T> where T: class
  {
    T GetByID(int id);
  }
```

I have a class that implements the interface, using LINQ to enties in project Data, which contains the class myClass:

```
  public class Test<myClass> :  ITest<myClass> where myClass : class
  {
      Data.myEntities _db = new Data.myEntities();

      public myClass GetByID(int id)
      {
        var item = _db.myClass.First(m => m.ID == id);
        return item;
      }

  }
```

This produces an error saying "Cannot implicitly convert type 'Data.myClass' to 'myClass', but if I change public class Test<myClass> to public class Test<Data.myClass> I get the "Type parameter declaration must be an identifier not a type".

I'm obviously missing something, because I don't understand what's going on here.  Can anyone explain it, or point to somewhere that might explain it better?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to just remove the generic parameter from the Test class.

```
... class Test : ITest<myClass> ...
```

as it stands now, the generic parameter name is shadowing the actual type name.

Comment: If I do that, the "where" gets an error stating "constraints are not allowed on non-generic declarations".

Comment: Oh, the 'where' bit can be removed too.

Comment: @chirs, your missing the point. You should also remove the Type constraint. In this case, you where creating a Generic parameter named myClass.

Comment: @bruno:  I'm pretty sure I'm missing something, which is why I asked the question :)  But at this point, I don't even know what I'm missing - I can make the changes you suggest, and it works, but I don't understand the difference.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is here:

```
 _db.myClass.First...
```

Is it possible you mean something like

```
_db.GetAll<myClass>().First...
```

I think you are confusing myClass as a type vs. myClass as a function _db implements?

Comment: No, that code works to return the myClass object with the specified ID using LINQ to Entites.

Comment: So you have a property of Data.myEntities for each T you might have an interface for?

Comment: Because if you do then GetByID has to be a big switch statement to call the right one based on typeof(myClass).